# How to handle aggregated field (sum) in a joined query?

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

Using SimpleSQL in Unity I am having trouble with a join query that includes an aggregated field (sum).

Entity class:

```
using SimpleSQL;

namespace Entity
{
    public class Song
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string gamer { get; set; }
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public string album { get; set; }
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public int mastery { get; set; }
        [Ignore]
        public int totalScore { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The query:

```
string sql = @"
    SELECT Song.gamer, Song.title, Song.artist, Song.album, Song.duration, Song.mastery, SUM(SongScore.score) as totalScore
    FROM Song
    INNER JOIN SongScore ON Song.gamer = SongScore.gamer AND Song.title = SongScore.songTitle AND Song.artist = SongScore.songArtist
    WHERE Song.gamer = ?
    GROUP BY Song.gamer, Song.title, Song.artist
    ORDER BY totalScore DESC
    LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;
";
```

I'm storing results in a `List<Song>`:

```
List<Song> results = _dbManager.Query<Song>(sql, gamerID, count, startIndex);
```

`totalScore` field is returned as 0 despite that it should be a calculated sum. When changing `totalScore` field type in the `Song` class to double instead of int the issue persists. [SimpleSQL documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jm6fpx8djz21fj8/SimpleSQL_UserManual.pdf?dl=1) mentions you can retrieve data from a table join and it will populate fields from joined tables in the class if they are defined. Since `totalScore` is an aggregated field I've marked it with the `[Ignore]` attribute to prevent it from being included in table operations. Why is the aggregated value not assigned to the `totalScore` field in the class?

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Song (
    gamer TEXT REFERENCES Gamer(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    artist TEXT NOT NULL,
    album TEXT NOT NULL,
    duration TEXT NOT NULL,
    mastery INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (gamer, title, artist)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SongScore (
    gamer TEXT REFERENCES Gamer(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    songTitle TEXT,
    songArtist TEXT,
    mapId INTEGER,
    score INTEGER NOT NULL,
    percentage REAL NOT NULL,
    attempts INTEGER NOT NULL,
    mastery INTEGER NOT NULL,
    attemptsToWin INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (gamer, mapId, songTitle, songArtist),
    FOREIGN KEY(songTitle, songArtist) REFERENCES Song(title, artist) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```